# Отправка SMS сообщения со своего номера телефона

Tags: java, sms

Как отправить SMS сообщение из приложения написанного на Java без использования SMS провайдеров типа [smsc](https://smsc.ru/) либо его аналогов?
Возможно ли отправить SMS сообщение со своего номера телефона?
Реализация на Android не подходит.

Answer (score 3):

Да, возможно. Нужно подключить телефон к компьютеру, как модем, открыть в программе COM-порт модема и слать в него соответствующие AT-команды. Либо взять одну из десятков библиотек, абстрагирующих взаимодействия с модемом, и вызвать соответствующий метод.

Comment: Arduino с GSM модулем или любой другой модем, хоть USB от местных провайдеров подойдёт для таких целей

Answer (score 2):

Есть хорошая программка, работающая под линуксом, - `Sms Server Tools 3`([сайт](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/)), очень проста и надежно работает.

Работает на отправку и прием.